# How to get the first process ID in MYSQL of the current user?

Tags: php, mysql, pid

I have tried the mysql query in phpmyadmin to get the pid and kill the process. Both of query listed below are work, however, it is through the phpmyadmin GUI.  How to **get the first pid using PHP**, How to get the first pid , and how to retrieve it ? For example : using mysql_fetch_array and treat it like running query "select from..." ? Thanks

```
Show processlist 


kill 'pid'
```

Comment: Why do you want the first process? Are you sure the first process is always the one you want to kill (in a multi-process/-thread environment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a MySQL server higher than 5.1.7 you can use a single SQL batch to do this:

```
SELECT @id := ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST LIMIT 1;
KILL @id;
```

Just use PDO or mysqli to run the batch.

Comment: Beware, this will just kill a random process, the one which happens to be first on the process list by chance. NOT a good idea if your server is actually doing anything of importance.

Comment: @intgr To be fair, you shouldn't ever blindly just copy code snippets and paste them into your codebase, but instead evaluate and implement the ideas behind them.